# Date to quarter

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to convert a given date to quarter.
This usually means (using floating point), I could use this algorithm in Nifi's expression language:

```
${start_dt
 :toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
 :format('MM','GMT')
 :toNumber()
 :divide(3)
 :plus(0.9)
 :toDecimal()}
```

The steps would be like this:

`2019-11-10T12:00:00+0000` -> `11` -> `11` -> `3.66666` -> `4.56666` -> `4`

`2019-12-10T12:00:00+0000` -> `12` -> `12` -> `4` -> `4.9` -> `4`

But instead I get 3.9 instead, only for Month 12 its working, so the toNumber() doesn't work.  As perdocumentation, I have to convert to Number before a division, so that I get floating points, but apparently that doesn't work.

I don't want to use a script just for this little calcualtion.

Nifi version is 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Using `divide(3.0)` instead of `divide(3)` solved the problem.
Documentation says, if one of the parameters is number, that one is used.  Since I'm not a native speaker, I also mixed up Number and Decimal. Decimals are the floats, Numbers are the integers.

Here the working algorithm:

```
${start_dt
:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
:format('MM','GMT')
:divide(3.0)
:plus(0.9)
:toNumber()}
```